# Create two instances of the player object instead of using the static one

Tags: javascript, html

I need to embed two video players on my web site. I have two snippets, but if I copy and paste both of them only one player is shown. Can you please help me to find the right way to create a single snippet for both?

**Player 1:**

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
       ipcamliveplayer.embed('mediadiv', 'cama1');
   });
</script>
<div id="mediadiv"></div>
```

**Player 2:**

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
       ipcamliveplayer.embed('mediadiv', 'cama2');
   });
</script>
<div id="mediadiv"></div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your two snippets of code are embeding in the same div `mediadiv` from what we can guess from your code.

Shouldn't you create two differents `div`s ? `mediadiv` and `mediadiv2` for example.

Comment: I tried to create differents divs, but only the second player is shown... Some told me this:
In this case you need to create two instances of the player object instead of using the static one:

var ipcamliveplayer1 = new iplayer();
ipcamliveplayer1 .embed('mediadiv1', alias1);

var ipcamliveplayer2 = new iplayer();
ipcamliveplayer1 .embed('mediadiv2', alias2);

But I don't know java, so I don't know where to start

Comment: First, this is not Java, it's Javascript. Big difference ! Without knowing what is `ipcamliveplayer` we can't help you. In your comment you wrote `ipcamliveplayer1.embed('mediadiv2', alias2)`, you should change to `ipcamliveplayer2.embed('mediadiv2', alias2)` first.

Comment: Thank you for your help. ipcamliveplayer is a playar, showing a live web cam. I tried this but no results: 

<script>  
   $(window).load(function() { 

var ipcamliveplayer1 = new iplayer();    ipcamliveplayer1.embed('mediadiv1', 'cama1');    
   });
  </script>

  <div id="mediadiv1" style="width: 100%; height: 410px;"> 
  </div>
<br />
<script>  
   $(window).load(function() { 
var ipcamliveplayer2 = new iplayer();    
ipcamliveplayer2.embed('mediadiv2', 'cama2');    
   });
  </script>

  <div id="mediadiv2" style="width: 100%; height: 410px;"> 
  </div>